# Why does sorting call the comparison function less often than a linear minimum search algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I'll start by giving some context. I'm learning to write a raytracer, a very simple one. I don't have any acceleration structures yet, so the code in question is intended to find the closest object that the ray hits. Since I'm learning yet, I'd greatly appreciate if the answers concentrated on the seemingly strange problem that I'm observing - I know the RT logic is very wrong as it is right now. It produces correct results, anyway.

**1.** The first approach: for every hit, add a hit-result structure object to the list, then apply `std::sort` with a predicate that compares the distance form the hit point to the ray origin. Should be `O(N log N)` according to the textbook, and *I think* it is suboptimal, since I only need the first result, not the whole sorted list.

**2.** The second approach: whenever there is a hit, take the distance and compare it to the minimum, which is first initialized to `std::numeric_limits<float>::max()`. Well, your standard "find min in the array" algorithm. Should be `O(N)` and thus faster.

These pieces of code reside in a recursive function. Tested on the very same scene of 10 spheres, **1** is faster by an order of magnitude. The amount of calls to the distance function is a few times less than in **2**. What am I missing?
I'm not sure if the context is required, in case there are "branches to be cut" off this question, tell me.

---

**Code piece 1**:

```
result rt_function(...) {
static int count{};
std::vector<result> hitList;
for(const auto& obj : objList) {
    const result res = obj->testOuter(ray);
    if ( res.hit ) {
        hitList.push_back(res);
    }
}
if (!hitList.empty()) {
    sort(hitList.begin(), hitList.end(), [=](result& hit1, result& hit2) -> bool {
            std::cerr << ++count << '\n';
            return cv::norm(hit1.point - ray.origin) <
                   cv::norm(hit2.point - ray.origin);
        });
    const result res = hitList.front();
    const SceneObject* near = res.obj;
    // the raytracing continues...
```

> count == 180771

---

**Code piece 2:**

```
result rt_function(...) {
static int count{};
float min_distance = std::numeric_limits<float>::max(), distance{};
result closest_res{}; bool have_hit{};
for(const auto& obj : objList) {
    const result res = obj->testOuter(ray);
    if ( res.hit ) {
        have_hit = true;
        std::cerr << ++count << '\n';
        distance = cv::norm(res.point - ray.origin);
        if (distance < min_distance) {
            min_distance = distance; closest_res = res;
        }
    }
}
if (have_hit) {
    const result res = closest_res;
    const SceneObject* near = res.obj;
    // the raytracing continues...
```

> count == 349633

I want to **(a)** understand why there are less comparisons and **(b)** where the bottleneck is, since the run time is significantly higher, as I've noted above.

Comment: It looks to me like the count for code snippet 1 is about twice that of code snippet 2, contrary to your description.

Comment: @user2357112 ouch got it, good catch!

Comment: @templatetypedef changed to capture by reference, got 180807, bit of a change but not much still. Anyway, I'm using the capture for the `ray` variable.

Comment: Any chance you ran these with the same `count` variable?

Comment: @user2357112 excuse me, not sure I catch it? These pieces of code are in different git branches. I checkout a branch, add the count statements, build, and run a few times both with and without the count statements. In both cases, 2 is slower. `-O3` is enabled in gcc.

Comment: Is `result` a costly to copy object? You are making more copies in your (2) snippet than in (1).

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot `result` is one bool, two vec3's, and one class pointer; I have only defined the default and custom constructors for it, not the copy or move ones, so a move constructor should be generated automatically. And, I really don't get it why there are more comparisons made!

Answer (score -1):

Statements like O(N²) are like a dimension; double the number of points and time taken quadruples.  An O(log N) algorithm can be slow for small N , the point being if N doubles or is increased by a factor of 10 running time doesn't.

Compare with finding a specific word in a 1000 page dictionary and one in a 20 word sentence. Sorting a 20 word sentence before finding a specific word takes longer than reading it straight through once.

Comment: True, but in this case sorting is actually faster, that's the trick.